# How to get profile photos from my telegram channels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram-api

I'm trying to make a correct request to Telegram API.

**Code:**

```
api.call('upload.getFile', {
    flags: 0,
    precise: false,
    cdn_supported:true,
    location: {
      _: 'inputPeerPhotoFileLocation',
      flags: 0,
      big: true,
      peer:{
        _: 'inputPeerChannel',
        channel_id: 'xxxxxx',
        access_hash: "xxxxxxxx"
      },   
      local_id: xxxxx,
      volume_id: "xxxxxx",
    },
    offset: 0,
    limit: 1024 * 1024,
    }).then(response => 
console.log(response))
}
```

It gives me an error:

> Uncaught (in promise)  {_: "rpc_error", error_code: 400,
> error_message: "FILE_ID_INVALID"} error_code: 400 error_message:
> "FILE_ID_INVALID"
> _: "rpc_error"

But I get all data for this request as answer on `api.call('channels.getAdminedPublicChannels')`.

What am I doing wrong?